# Clustering markers with infowindow in googlemaps v3 api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I cant get the ClustererMarker to work. I want markers to cluster when they are close to each other and I have found:

```
var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

But I cant get them to work with my code, either all markers disappear or only one is visible (not in the correct way). I hope someone can help me with my problem.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
        });

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i)); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have made it more minimal now! I Hope someone can help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

```
var gmarkers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
            });

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i)); 

gmarkers.push(marker);
}   

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
```